# Make column blank, but give it ID of tdInnerHtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, innerhtml, visual-web-developer

Software: Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition

I am reading "Programming ASP.NET 3.5", and it says to create a web application with a table

[image]

The book says

> Leave the second column in the last row empty, but give it an ID of
>   tdInnerHtml

How to do this? I tried

[image]

But when I have to reference itInnerHtml in the doce, it doesn't render. Note the red squiggly line under tdInnerHtml

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the tag `runat="server"` on your cell:

```
<td id="tdInnerHtml" runat="server">
...
...
...
```